# Definite Integral Property $\int^{c + h}_{a} f - \int^{c}_{a} f = \int^{c + h}_{c} f$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

My textbook states the following:

> Suppose $c$ is in $[a, b]$. Since $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$ it is, by definition, bounded on $[a, b]$. If $h > 0$, then $\int^{c + h}_{a} f - \int^{c}_{a} f = \int^{c + h}_{c} f$.

I do not understand the reasoning behind $\int^{c + h}_{a} f - \int^{c}_{a} f = \int^{c + h}_{c} f$. I thought it may be a property of definite integrals, but I can't find anything online.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain how the author got $\int^{c + h}_{c} f$ from $\int^{c + h}_{a} f - \int^{c}_{a} f$.

Comment: Do you mean a rigourous explanation? Otherwise it's plain obvious. Also, I presume by integrable you mean Riemann integrable? If not, $f$ need not be bounded on $[a,b]$

Comment: $\int\limits_c^{c+h}=\int\limits_c^a+\int\limits_a^{c+h}=\int_a^{c+h}-\int\limits_a^c$

Comment: @user160738 Just an elementary explanation of the operation will suffice. The textbook hasn't mentioned Riemann integrals yet.

Comment: @AdityaNarayanSharma Oh, I see: You simply used the property that we can flip the bounds and take the negative?

Comment: Precisely @The Pointer

Comment: @AdityaNarayanSharma Ok. Thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same thing, but you could look at it like $$\int_a^{c+h}f(x) dx = \int_a^cf(x) dx + \int_c^{c+h}f(x) dx$$ which is one of the basic properties of definite integrals, and then you subtract $\int_a^cf(x) dx$ from both sides.

In fact, you can apply this property multiple times to get 
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^{b_1}f(x)dx + \int_{b_1}^{b_2}f(x)dx + \cdots+ \int_{b_n-1}^{b_n}f(x)dx + \int_{b_n}^{b}f(x)dx$$